# Вопрос по MySQL Server 5.5 - ошибка ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql

На одном ПК (MySQL-сервер шёл в паке от Denwer - MySQL версии 5.5)
Там открываю mysql.exe, он сразу срабатывает. Открывается консоль mySQL
На другом ПК установил MySQL из пакета MySQL Installer Community (официальный инсталлятор MySQL-Сервера)
На нём при открывании файла mysql.exe сразу ошибка.
Пробовал через команду: `mysql.exe -uroot -p[password]`. Та же ошибка:
MySQL Server 5.5, ошибка: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`.
Хотя сам MySQL сервер работает. Базы открываются, редактируются.
С консолью MySQL опыта нет.
Как это исправить?
И почему в одном случае консоль работает, а в другом нет?

---

UPD:
если указывать:
`mysql.exe -uroot -p[password] --host=localhost` - то тоже самое (Еггог 2003).
А если:
`mysql.exe -uroot -p[password] --host=127.0.0.1` - то присоединяется и консоль открывается.

Comment: Если не сложно приведите my.ini того сервера, где не устанавливается соединение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило любое консольное приложение, если ему не указать аргументы при запуске, запускается со значениями аргументами по умолчанию. Что в вашем случае и происходит - клиент пытается подключиться к БД на локальном компьютере, которой у вас нет. 
Так же как правило консольные приложения предоставляют справку по возможным аргументам. Для этого существуют стандартные аргументы `-?` `-h` `/h` `-help`
Для подключения к удалённому серверу воспользуйтесь командой
`mysql --host=hostname --user=myname`, где `hostname` это имя компьютера с БД или его IP-адрес

Comment: БД-то у меня есть 100% и коннектился я к ней через GUI, а здесь возникла необходимость автоматизировать процесс обновления БД в разных городах, вот и решил сделать cmd'шку используя консоль mySQL

Comment: @I_CaR, тогда я не понял почему вы приняли мой ответ.

Comment: я уже не помню чем руководствовался принимая Ваш ответ, но думаю в тот момент он меня натолкнул на какую-то, исправляющую ситуацию, мысль.